# WebSphere MQ Get - Filter messages by MachineName

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

We are a team of developers that use the same WebSphere MQ queue to write and read messages. Because we use the same queue some messages are picked up by a reader from another machine. 
Is there a way to filter the messages that are read from the queue, by the *Environment.MachineName* of the sender?

This is what I tried fo far by using *MQMessage.GroupId*:

1. Set GroupId on the messages that are **PUT**.
2. Set *MQGetMessageOptions.MatchOptions = MQC.MQMO_MATCH_GROUP_ID* for the **GET** and set *GroupId* on message.

Basically I am trying to make a group for each workstation that uses the queue. Unfortunatelly this doesn't work, no messages are read by the **GET**.

Is there another option to implement what I need?
I am using *WebSphere MQ 7.0.1* and *amqmdnet.dll* *WebSphere MQ Classes for .NET*.

Thanks in advance,
Radu

Comment: There is this feature called Selectors but I haven't found the corresponding .NET components, yet.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.csqzal.doc/fg20160_.htm?cp=SSFKSJ_7.0.1%2F1-7-0-2-4-1&lang=en

Comment: Have you found a solution eventually?

Answer (score 0):

OMG.  Don't do this - it is a horrible design.  The better solution is to create many queues, so that each queue handles a unique function.
i.e.

- BANK.ACCOUNT.LIST
- BANK.ACCOUNT.DEPOSIT
- BANK.ACCOUNT.WITHDRAWAL
- BANK.ACCOUNT.TRANSFER

There is absolutely no reason to have several applications put messages to the same queue if the messages are for different purposes.

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply.
We have several applications only in the development environment since we are multiple developers coding/testing/debugging. We don't have the option to create a queue per developer.
There must be a way to filter messages when reading, something generic.

Comment: Thats non-sense.  Just ask your MQAdmin to create a set of 'production-like' queues for each developer in your TEST/SANDBOX environment.  To replicate a set of queues takes about 90 seconds, so there is absolutely no reason not to do it.

Comment: I already mentioned that: We don't have the option to create a queue per developer.